# ejabberd on openshift - Failed RPC connection to the node

Tags: sed, xmpp, ejabberd, openshift

I am trying to configure ejabberd on DIY cartridge on openshift, following the guide here:

[Erlang and Ejabberd on OpenShift](http://blog.pyjeon.com/?p=488#comment-877)

I followed everything successsfully up to here:

`Next you can start ejabberd running the following 2 commands, which you’ll want to put in your .openshift/action_hooks/start script`

there is no error and ejabberd seems to be started, but the next command:

```
$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/erl_home/sbin/ejabberdctl register admin localhost password1234
```

failed with this error:

```
Failed RPC connection to the node ‘ejabberd@127.7.131.1′: {‘EXIT’, {badarg, [{ets,lookup, [local_config, ejabberdctl_access_commands], []}, {ejabberd_config, get_local_option, 1, [{file, "ejabberd_config.erl"}, {line,590}]}, {ejabberd_ctl, get_accesscommands, 0, [{file, "ejabberd_ctl.erl"}, {line,236}]}, {ejabberd_ctl, process,1, [{file, "ejabberd_ctl.erl"}, {line,199}]}, {rpc, ‘-handle_call_call/6-fun-0-’, 5, [{file, "rpc.erl"}, {line,205}]}]}}

Commands to start an ejabberd node: start Start an ejabberd node in server mode debug Attach an interactive Erlang shell to a running ejabberd node live Start an ejabberd node in live (interactive) mode

Optional parameters when starting an ejabberd node: –config-dir dir Config ejabberd: /var/lib/openshift/52c9674d5973ca7734000180/app-root/data//erl_home/etc/ejabberd –config file Config ejabberd: /var/lib/openshift/52c9674d5973ca7734000180/app-root/data//erl_home/etc/ejabberd/ejabberd.cfg –ctl-config file Config ejabberdctl: /var/lib/openshift/52c9674d5973ca7734000180/app-root/data//erl_home/etc/ejabberd/ejabberdctl.cfg –logs dir Directory for logs: /var/lib/openshift/52c9674d5973ca7734000180/app-root/data//erl_home/var/log/ejabberd –spool dir Database spool dir: /var/lib/openshift/52c9674d5973ca7734000180/app-root/data//erl_home/var/lib/ejabberd –node nodename ejabberd node name: ejabberd@127.7.131.1
```

I am not sure what causes the error... it seems like it is trying to connect to localhost (due to the nodename: ejabberd@127.7.131.1). However, I have `sed` every localhost smell from the previous commands on the blog.

Anybody ever encounter this before? Any clue on how to debug is also highly appreciated, as I am not very familiar with openshift or ejabberd as well as linux... Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote the blog post, and saw this error on a new DIY Application I created.  It was due to a bug with erlang and the openssl package in the openshift box.  I put in a patch in the erlang source so that new compilations will work.

The bug that was causing the issue was here: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1023017

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to run using your host instead of localhost.

```
$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/erl_home/sbin/ejabberdctl register admin <replacewithyourhost> password1234
```

Comment: Thanks 4 d reply, I tried: $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/erl_home/sbin/ejabberdctl register admin $OPENSHIFT_DIY_IP password1234
however it returns error as well:
{error_logger,{{2014,1,13},{21,11,24}},"Protocol: ~tp: register/listen error: ~tp~n",["inet_tcp",econnrefused]}
{error_logger,{{2014,1,13},{21,11,24}},crash_report,[[{initial_call,{net_kernel,init,['Argument__1']}},{pid,<0.20.0>},{registered_name,[]},{error_info,{exit,{error,badarg},[{gen_server,init_it,6,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,320}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,239}]}]}}...

Answer (score 0):

For that

`OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/erl_home/sbin/ejabberdctl register admin $OPENSHIFT_DIY_IP password1234`

However it returns error as well:

```
 {error_logger,{{2014,1,13},{21,11,24}},"Protocol: ~tp: register/listen error: ~tp~n",["inet_tcp",econnrefused]} {error
```

above

You need to kill all the ejabberd process including epmd.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem one time, My solution was to edit /etc/hosts(for windows- C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts) file and make sure that there was a hostname entry for my public ip address and the domain I wanted ejabber to respond to.

0.0.0.0 hostname.domain.com hostname

1.1.1.1(your ip) your-hostname.your-domain your-hostname